# What to encrypt a file using PGP and upload to S3 AWS

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pgp

I'm running lambda batch job to upload files in S3.I want to encrypt file using PGP encryption and upload to AWS S3, using java.Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Worth checking AWS Encryption SDK for java [aws sdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/java.html)
- I think Bouncy Castle should be of help here. [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/java-example-code.html)

Comment: @amittin  how we encrypt a file using PGP in java. Can you please post any sample code.

Comment: @UdayTej a bit confused are you trying to encrypt a file and then save it to s3 which is again encrypting it

Comment: yes @amittin using PGP.im trying to  encrypt a file using PGP and save the encrypted file in  S3

Comment: cri.uday@gmail.com @amittn

Comment: @UdayTej I have updated the ans with examples please check

Comment: @amittin I think they are using PGP. We need PGP public key  to pass and encrypt it